# Mypage.aspx.cs throws a compiler error: class does not contain a constructor that takes 0 argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor

MyPage.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Mypage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public IConfigurationClient _configurationClient;
 
    public MyPage(IConfigurationClient configurationClient )
    {
        _configurationClient = configurationClient ;
    }
 
    //rest of the code
}
```

I am not sure what the issue is. I have also tried extending the base constructor with no arguments, but it still does not work.

```
public MyPage(IConfigurationClient configurationClient) : base()
{
    _configurationClient = configurationClient ;
}
```

Furthermore, I have tried adding a parameterless constructor which solves the issue but when I call
`_configurationClient.GetConfigAsync()` it gives an object reference error as _configurationClient is null.

Comment: The ASP.net runs your page cycle, it is not a manual job. It is expecting a constructor with no arguments

Answer (score 2):

If this is the only constructor available in code, it won't work because a constructor with zero arguments is expected. You could inject the needed argument using method injection instead of constructor injection.

```
public void SetConfigurationClient(IConfigurationClient client)
{
    _configurationClient = client;
}
```